# Is there any way to get permission with protection level "signature" in Android with root

Tags: android, android-permissions

I want to use the permission android.permission.DEVICE_POWER in my App, and I kown this permission is under protection level "signature".

Now I want to find a way to get the permission on a rooted device, but I do not want to compile the rom and sign with my key, this may make the app only run on my device.

I tried to move the apk to the /system/priv-app, but it always faield to grant the permission.

So is there any way to achieve this or still no way to do?

Comment: This should not be possible. `system` permissions can be gotten on rooted devices by moving your app to the `system` partition. `signature` permissions should be doing an actual signing key check and root won't really change that.

Comment: does it not now need to be in `/system/priv` ? `/system/` is now reserved for bloatware and / or bundles apps that dont need any extra permissions but should be uninstalled